# Call oracle procedure with an empty cursor?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a procedure that looks like this:

```
  PROCEDURE myprocedure (
      i_area        IN       somenumber%TYPE,
      io_areadata   IN OUT   areacursor
   );
```

And I wonder if there is any simple way to call procedure? I have data for the first argument but for the second I do not know what enter. Is there any way I could enter an empty cursor or  something similar?

This is what I've done so far:

```
BEGIN
package.myprocedure (
      12345
   );
END;
```

And that gives me the following error:

```
Error report:
ORA-06550: row 2, column 1:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'MYPROCEDURE'
ORA-06550: row 2, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
```

Thank you in advance and sorry for my (maybe) poor explanation. I have little experience in PL/SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to supply that parameter.  You could do this:

```
DECLARE
   dummy package.areacursor;
BEGIN
package.myprocedure (
      12345, dummy
   );
END;
```

Comment: Did not work: `ORA-06550: row 2, column 9:
PLS-00201: identifier 'areacursor' must be declared
ORA-06550: row 2, column 9:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: row 5, column 16:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed`

Comment: See updated answer - I guess type areacursor is declared in the package.

Answer (score 0):

By this way you can call a stored procedure by passing particular value to a particular parameter.
Try this.

```
Begin

package.myprocedure(i_area => '12345);

end;
```